# Validating Promos using Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I am running the 'def' function separately, they are giving the correct result. However When I am combining 'def' functions of Promos in one, it is giving an error.
Not able to get what the problem is. New to Selenium. Please, help.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class elementbyid (unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver =  webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        cls.driver.get("http://demo.magentocommerce.com/")

    def test_vip_promo(self):
        vippromo = self.driver.\
            find_element_by_xpath("//img[@alt='Shop Private Sales - Members Only']")
        self.assertTrue(vippromo.is_displayed())
        vippromo.click()
        self.assertEqual("VIP", self.driver.title)
        self.driver.get("http://demo.magentocommerce.com/")

    def test_home_decor(self):
        hdecor = self.driver.\
            find_element_by_xpath("//img[@alt='Physical & Virtual Gift Cards']")
        self.assertTrue(hdecor.is_displayed())
        hdecor.click()
        self.assertEqual("Home & Decor", self.driver.title)
        self.driver.get("http://demo.magentocommerce.com/")

    def test_bags_luggage(self):
        blug = self.driver.\
            find_element_by_xpath("//img[@alt='Travel Gear for Every Occasion']")
        self.assertTrue(blug.is_displayed())
        blug.click()
        self.assertEqual('Bags & Luggage - Accessories', self.driver.title)
        self.driver.get("http://demo.magentocommerce.com/")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
```

Comment: @Stanjer - Error  is : Failure
Expected :'VIP'
Actual   :'Madison Island'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\LEARNING\code\Test2.py", line 18, in test_vip_promo
    self.assertEqual("VIP", self.driver.title)
AssertionError: 'VIP' != 'Madison Island'
- VIP
+ Madison Island

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you run these functions back-to-back, the page doesn't have time to load.

The [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) has a command "waitForVisible", which is implemented in the Python WebDriver export like this:

```
for i in range(60):
    try:
        if driver.find_element_by_id("first_name").is_displayed(): break
    except: pass
    time.sleep(1)
else: self.fail("time out")
```

If you set it to wait for an element that is unique to the page you want, then your asserts will be running against the correct page.

This blog post on [How to get Selenium to wait for page load after a click](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html) might also be worth reading.

Comment: Thanks Travis for blog link and answer... I just replaced the [self.driver.get("http://demo.magentocommerce.com/")]                                from above 3 def test with [self.driver.back()] , and it script worked as expected.